# Why mysql Insert into query not working in php application

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

When execute the query it's not working, it will print error. $q also not coming when i'm print it. but $_SESSION["username"]; is working?

```
      <?php
      session_start();
     $_SESSION["username"];

      include 'Db_Connection.php';
      $q= $_GET[q];

    $username= $_SESSION[username];

   echo $username;
    echo $q;

    $sql="INSERT INTO search(searcher,searched_time,searched_email) 
      VALUES ('$username',NOW(),'$q')";                   

     $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

     if($result)
       {
    echo "Success";

        }
       else
       {
       echo "Error";

          }
     ?>
```

Comment: I don't know if this is just a formatting problem with your post, but if your code actually looks like that, please consider adopting a standard method of indentation. It'll help you recognize nesting problems, missing parens, and other things, as well as making it far easier for others to interpret your code. Also, if this is handling input coming from a user, please look into PHP's MySQL built-in parameter handling/escaping methods to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: comment  /* echo $username;
    echo $q; */ and see what is the result

Comment: What is "q"? and where is the value of `$_SESSION[username];` ? I mean the word username needs a $ before or double quotes, no idea what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things I can pick up from your provided code.

1. Your second line `$_SESSION["username"];` is superfluous as it does nothing
2. You are using the mysql_* functions which are deprecated
3. You are not using prepared statements for inserting variables into your query

try something like this:

```
session_start();

//start assuming this is in your connection file
$con = new mysqli("db-ip-address", "db-user", "db-pass", "db-name")
//end assuming

$q= $_GET[q];

$username= $_SESSION[username];

echo $username;
echo $q;

$sql="INSERT INTO search(searcher,searched_time,searched_email) VALUES (?,NOW(),?)";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $q);
$result = $stmt->execute();

if($result) {
    echo "Success";
} else {
    echo "Error";
}

//remember to cleanup connections etc
```

as far as the value $q not printing out, make sure that the value is set via the GET query string `http://someurl.com/somefile.php?q=some-value` and that `$q` is not some weird non-printable value. If you want to confirm that the value is set, try running `var_dump($_GET)` to output the contents of your `$_GET` array to ensure there is actually a value being set.

Comment: `$q= $_GET['q'];` instead of `$q= $_GET[q];` and `$_SESSION['username'];` instead of `$_SESSION[username];`

Comment: good pickup, I will admit I copy/pasted from the original code, although PHP does assume an uninitialized constant as its string form with a warning, so while I am wrong, it would still work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is your problem:

```
$q= $_GET[q];
```

q should be surrounded in quotes, e.g.:

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
```

Other than that, what Damon said was completely correct.